# Linker Error when finding the display size

Tags: c++, winapi, hyperlink, linker

I Am trying to find the size of the desktop monitor using GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) and GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN). As soon as I add this to my code I get errors such as:

3 Unresovled externals.
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __stdcall GetSystemMetrics(int)"

I think I need to link win32 but when i add #pragma comment(lib, "win32.lib") to my code I also get an error saying it cannot find it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: give User32.lib a try in place of win32.lib

Comment: It worked. You saved the day man, much love.